# how to stop a toggle script from ending when a link is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the below code to show/hide a nav and its children. It is working as intended. When the nav shows, and I click on one of the child links, it closes, and then takes me to a new page.

```
 // swap classes for lower level nav
  jQuery('.toggle').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('toggle');
  $(this).toggleClass('toggle_open');
 });

 jQuery('a.portfolio').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
 });
```

It doesn't do this with Safari, but Chrome & Firefox display the behaviour above. When I watch what is happening when the inspector is open; I click on the parent link, the toggle class is applied, I click on a child link, and the toggle class gets swapped back.

**How do I stop the nav from closing before it takes me to the requested page?**

My markup (unconventional for a nav - i know):

```
<span class="toggle">
 <a href="portfolio/" class="level1 portfolio">Portfolio</a>
   <span>
     <a href="portfolio/item1/" class="first level2">item 1</a>
     <a href="portfolio/item2/" class="level2">item 2</a>
     <a href="portfolio/item3/" class="last level2">item 3</a>
   </span>   
</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `e.stopPropagation()` to all `<a>`'s click handler, and remove `e. preventDefault()` which will prevent you from going to a new page.

Try this code:

```
jQuery('.toggle').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('toggle');
  $(this).toggleClass('toggle_open');
 });

 jQuery('.toggle a.level2').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
 });
```

Comment: If I do this, I wont be able to click on the child links. I just don't want my toggle script to end once I click on another link.

Answer (score 0):

Try `e.stopPropagation()` to prevent calling additional event handlers. You may need to change the order of your event handlers.

Comment: I've added a `e.stopPropagation()` for .toggle_open, but its still switching to .toggle when i click on a child link.

Comment: infact adding `e.stopPropagation()` stops me from being able to click on the child links. Once my toggle script has run, I don't want it to end if another link is clicked